# run multiple instances of a class simultaneously javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

You probably only need to look at obstacle.js

I have a class which draws a square on a canvas and adds collision detection to it.

When I create one instance it works perfectly,

```
new Obstacle(100, 100, 100, 100).init()
```

but if I create 2 it only works on the second one I create

```
new Obstacle(100, 100, 100, 100).init()
new Obstacle(400, 100, 100, 100).init()
```

does anyone know a way to make this code work on **both** instances?

```js
// utility.js

//define variables
let Keys = {
  W: false,
  A: false,
  S: false,
  D: false
}

let Allow = {
  W: true,
  A: true,
  S: true,
  D: true
}

let Character = {
  X: 0,
  Y: 0,
  H: parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("height")),
  W: parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("width")),
}

//function to update the position of `character` every milisecond
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("character").style.left = Character.X + "px"
  document.getElementById("character").style.top = Character.Y + "px"
}, 1)

//waits for event `keyDOWN` to happen, if it happens it sets `Keys.` + the key to TRUE so it START animating
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "w") Keys.W = true
  if (event.key === "a") Keys.A = true
  if (event.key === "s") Keys.S = true
  if (event.key === "d") Keys.D = true
})

//waits for event `keyUP` to happen, if it happens it sets `Keys.` + the key to FALSE so it STOPS animating
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "w") Keys.W = false
  if (event.key === "a") Keys.A = false
  if (event.key === "s") Keys.S = false
  if (event.key === "d") Keys.D = false
})

//function that makes `character` move by adding to its X and Y value
setInterval(function() {
  if (Keys.W && Allow.W) {
    if (Character.Y > 0) {
      Character.Y -= 1
    }
  }
  if (Keys.A && Allow.A) {
    if (Character.X > 0) {
      Character.X -= 1
    }
  }
  if (Keys.S && Allow.S) {
    if (Character.Y < 500 - Character.H) {
      Character.Y += 1
    }
  }
  if (Keys.D && Allow.D) {
    if (Character.X < 800 - Character.W) {
      Character.X += 1
    }
  }
}, 1)


// obstacle.js

//define variables
let canvas = document.getElementById("ObstacleHolder")
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
//resize the canvas
canvas.width = 800
canvas.height = 500

class Obstacle {
  constructor(x, y, height, width, src = null) {
    this.H = height
    this.W = width
    this.X = x
    this.Y = y
    this.src = src
  }

  //function to draw the obstacle on the canvas & apply colision detection
  init() {
    //array for the coordinates
    let ObstaclePositions = [this.X - Character.W, this.Y - Character.H, (this.X + this.W), (this.Y + this.H)]
    //draw the obstacle on the canvas
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.rect(this.X, this.Y, this.W, this.H)
    ctx.fillStyle = "Red"
    ctx.fill()

    //colision detection
    setInterval(function() {
      //colision detection X
      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] && Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] && Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] - 1 && Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2] - 1) {
        Allow.D = false
        Allow.A = true
        Allow.S = true
        Allow.W = true
      } else {
        Allow.D = true
      }

      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] && Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] && Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] + 1 && Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2] + 1) {
        Allow.A = false
        Allow.D = true
        Allow.S = true
        Allow.W = true
      } else {
        Allow.A = true
      }

      //colision detection Y
      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] - 1 && Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] - 1 && Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] && Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2]) {
        Allow.S = false
        Allow.D = true
        Allow.A = true
        Allow.W = true
      } else {
        Allow.S = true
      }

      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] + 1 && Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] + 1 && Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] && Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2]) {
        Allow.W = false
        Allow.A = true
        Allow.D = true
        Allow.S = true
      } else {
        Allow.W = true
      }
    }, 1)
  }
}

new Obstacle(100, 100, 100, 100).init()
new Obstacle(400, 100, 100, 100).init()
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Dosis", "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#character {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 204, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#ObstacleHolder {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 158, 0.288);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Prototype</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="canvas">
    <canvas id="ObstacleHolder"></canvas>
    <div id="character"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<!-- import css file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<!-- import javascript files -->
<script src="utility.js"></script>
<script src="obstacle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: It looks like every Obstacle instance updates the same "Allow" object. Is that right?

Comment: @Pointy yes that is correct

Comment: So when the interval handler for one Obstacle runs, a few milliseconds later the handler for the other Obstacle will run, overwriting Allow with new values.

Comment: @Pointy okay that makes sense, do you know how i can fix that?

Comment: Yes: on every tick, initialize Allow to allow everything, and each obstacle will only block (without overwriting the rest).

Comment: **Extra Tip:** Running a `setInterval` on each millisecond will probably be too much work. Try [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.

Comment: @emi So i'd just set all pointers in Allow to true every milisecond?

Comment: Yes. And you'll probably want to do a unique `setInterval` to generate a `tick` manager. This manager then calls all Obstacles `tick` callbacks, or allow them to subscribe to a `onTick` event triggered from the `tick` manager. This way you will have a coherent result.

Comment: @emi when i try it it doesnt work, could you maybe write it for me? if thats not to much to ask, its okay if it is.

Comment: Have you already wrote your own tick manager?!?!?

Comment: @emi no i set it to true every frame, to be honest i dont know what a tick manager is, im just a beginner

Comment: Read previous comments, please

Comment: ohhhh excuse me

Comment: @emi im sorry i just dont get it, i dont know what this line "And you'll probably want to do a unique setInterval to generate a tick manager. This manager then calls all Obstacles tick callbacks, or allow them to subscribe to a onTick event triggered from the tick manager" even means

Comment: I'm writing an answer

Comment: @emi okay thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Create your `TickManager` (this one, based on `EventEmitter`):

```js
class TickManager extends EventEmitter {
  timer = false;
  running = false;

  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
    this.onStop = this.stop.bind(this);
    this.on('stop', this.onStop);
  }

  destroy(...props) {
    this.off('stop', this.onStop);
    super.destroy(...props);
  }

  start() {
    if(!this.running) {
      this.running = true;
      this.tick();
    }
  }

  stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.timer);
    this.running = false;
  }

  tick() {
    this.timer = false;
    this.emit( 'beforetick' );
    this.emit( 'tick' );
    this.emit( 'aftertick' );
    if(this.running) {
      this.timer = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick.bind(this));
    }
  }
}

const tickManager = new TickManager();
```

Use it in your player:

```js
tickManager.on('beforetick', function() {
  Allow = {
    W: true,
    A: true,
    S: true,
    D: true
  };

  // Allow obstacles to disallow directions
  tickManager.emit('afterplayertick');
});

// Update the position of `character` after all calculations have been done
tickManager.on('aftertick', function() {
  document.getElementById("character").style.left = Character.X + "px"
  document.getElementById("character").style.top = Character.Y + "px"
});

// Makes `character` move by adding to its X and Y value, if allowed by obstacles
tickManager.on('tick', function() {
  if (Keys.W && Allow.W) {
    if (Character.Y > 0) {
      Character.Y -= 1
    }
  }
  if (Keys.A && Allow.A) {
    if (Character.X > 0) {
      Character.X -= 1
    }
  }
  if (Keys.S && Allow.S) {
    if (Character.Y < 500 - Character.H) {
      Character.Y += 1
    }
  }
  if (Keys.D && Allow.D) {
    if (Character.X < 800 - Character.W) {
      Character.X += 1
    }
  }
});
```

Use it in your obstacles:

```js
class Obstacle {
  // ...
  init() {
    // ...
    // Colision detection
    tickManager.on('afterplayertick', function() {
      //colision detection X
      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] &&
          Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] &&
          Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] - 1 &&
          Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2] - 1) {
        Allow.D = false
      }
      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] &&
          Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] &&
          Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] + 1 &&
          Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2] + 1) {
        Allow.A = false
      }
      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] - 1 &&
          Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] - 1 &&
          Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] &&
          Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2]) {
        Allow.S = false
      }
      if (Character.Y > ObstaclePositions[1] + 1 &&
          Character.Y < ObstaclePositions[3] + 1 &&
          Character.X > ObstaclePositions[0] &&
          Character.X < ObstaclePositions[2]) {
        Allow.W = false
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And, finally, start the tick manager:

```js
tickManager.start();
```

#### EventEmitter

You can use `EventEmitter` from [NPM Event package](https://preview.npmjs.com/package/events?activeTab=readme) or do it yourself (copied from [this article](https://medium.com/@contactsachinsingh/how-to-implement-eventemitter-in-javascript-e4f4ff224e84)):

```js
class EventEmitter {
  listeners = [];
  emit(eventName, data) {
    this.listeners
      .filter(({ name }) => name === eventName)
      .forEach(
        ({ callback }) => setTimeout(
          callback.apply(this, [this, ...data]), 0
        );
      )
  }
  on(name, callback) {
    if (
      typeof callback === 'function'
      && typeof name === 'string'
    ) {
      this.listeners.push({ name, callback });
    }
  }
  off(eventName, callback) {
    this.listeners = this.listeners.filter(
      listener => !(listener.name === eventName &&
        listener.callback === callback)
    );
  }
  destroy() {
    this.listeners.length = 0;
  }
}
```

There are lots of other impovements you can do to this code:

- Create a `Player` class (so you can have more than one!). Add the `Keys`, `Allow`, `Character` and DOM element to it.
- Pass the tick manager as an argument to players and obstacles creators, so you stop using the same context and can start `import`ing modules to split and organize your code.
- In this example, the player emits an event. Pass the player as an argument to its listeners, so the obstacles listeners can control the collision against each player.

Comment: when i just paste all of the code blocks into my file i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: EventEmitter is not defined at obstacle.js:1"

Comment: Added help on `EventEmitter`

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: data is not iterable
    at obstacle.js:8
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TickManager.emit (obstacle.js:6)
    at TickManager.tick (obstacle.js:36)
    at obstacle.js:126"

Comment: Well, you'll need `tickManager` to be accessible from `obstacle.js`. I don't know how you made `Allow` accessible from there: it should be the same way.

Comment: Or, still better, follow the final Tips, where each created element receives `tickManager` as an argument in its constructor, or in some abstracted `init` function.

Comment: Fixed `start`/`stop` mechanism.